# Make a filter query search multiple columns | Symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony-1.4, doctrine-query

I am working on an Symfony 1.4 project and need to customize a backend filter "name", so that the column "name_full" is searched simultaneously with the "name" column.

I thought of doing it like that in my FormFilterClass:

```
public function addNameColumnQuery(Doctrine_Query $query, $field, $value) {

    $rootAlias = $query->getRootAlias();
    return $query->where(''.$rootAlias.'.name LIKE ?', "%$value%")
                 ->orWhere(''.$rootAlias.'.name_full LIKE ?', "%$value%");
}
```

but that doesn't work as it gives me a wrong result set. And I fail to find the file where I could dump the complete dql for debugging.

Please point out where I could dump the complete dql or even tell me what is wrong with my approach.

Thank you!

EDIT: This is the correct function as suggested by Michal and tweaked by me:

```
public function addNameColumnQuery(Doctrine_Query $query, $field, $value)
{
    $rootAlias = $query->getRootAlias();
    return  $query->addWhere(
        ''.$rootAlias.'.name LIKE ? OR '.$rootAlias.'.name_full LIKE ?',
        array($value, $value)
    );
}
```

Comment: I found out that I will have to overload doBuildQuery() in my FilterFormClass. How exactly do to what I want? I am still hunting for the solution.

Comment: You can check the query from the development toolbar when you use the dev environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this to:

```
$query->addWhere(
    '$rootAlias.'.name LIKE ? OR '.$rootAlias.'.name_full LIKE ?',
    array("%$value%", "%$value%")
);
```

By using `->where()` you overwrite the whole where part of the query so you could be deleting some conditions that were applied before the function `addNameColumnQuery` was called.
Also by using the above statement you will make sure that the two conditions joined with `OR` will be in parenthesis, so you will have

```
condition1 AND condition2 AND (name LIKE '' OR name LIKE '')
```

not

```
condition1 AND condition2 AND name LIKE '' OR name LIKE ''
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Michal! I had to slightly tweak your function (see edit above) but now it works a treat!